# SqlAlchemy makes strange implicit queries

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have relation in my user model

```
photos = relationship('UserPhoto', backref='user', lazy='joined')
```

After I get all entries with

```
users = query.all()
```

SA makes query with LEFT OUTER JOIN to userPhoto table

I start to iterate over them and print all properties
And suddenly SA makes strange implicit queries for each entry

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT users.id AS users_id, ... FROM users 
WHERE users.id = %(param_1)s
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'param_1': <integer idetifier>}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT user_photo.id... FROM user_photo 
WHERE %(param_1)s = user_photo.user_id
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'param_1': <integer idetifier>}
```

I've spent a few hours to find out the reason, but still searching

If I construct joins myself like below:

```
query.options(joinedload_all('some field'))
```

SA makes only one select with join

Comment: there's some kind of lazy loading going on here but not enough detail to see at what point it needs to load users again, user_photo, etc.  there's all kinds of reasons objects might not be loaded, depends on the scenario.   If i make a simple test with User, User.photos and lazy="joined", a straight load will run just one SQL statement including as I iterate.